# How to pass data dynamically to a Widget class inside Model

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-navigation

I have a model like this:

```dart
class MyModel{
  Widget widget;
  MyModel(this.widget);
}

var myPage = MyModel(HomeWidget());
```

is there a way to pass data to `HomeWidget()` using model when i use it? like this?

```dart
myPage.widget("some data")
```

or any way to pass data to widget dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try callback like way

```dart
class MyModel{
  Function(String data) widget;
  MyModel(this.widget);
}

var myPage = MyModel((String data) => HomeWidget(data));
```

```dart
myPage.widget("some data");
```